# What paradoxes did David Hilbert propose?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, hilbert

Google just won't tell me about any other than "the grand hotel". I know of the Turing paradox but did he propose any other? If yes, which?

Comment: What is the link between so-called [Turing paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Zeno_effect) and Hilbert?

Comment: See [Paradoxes and Contemporary Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paradoxes-contemporary-logic/#MathContHilbZerm) for reference to Hilbert's unpublished works on some well-known paradoxes.